# How do I output a working [shortcode] in WordPress using ACF Options Page Field with Timber/Twig

Tags: wordpress, forms, twig, timber, acfpro

I am trying to output a working [shortcode] on my contact page from a ACF Options Page "text" field in WordPress (using twig/timber) and it just outputs the string on the page instead of the whole contact form - not sure what to do next?

I am trying: `{{options.form.contact|raw}}` but just outputs `[contact-form-7 id="371" title="Contact form 1"]` my dump of `{{dump(options.form.contact)}}` outputs:

`~wordpress\app\public\wp-content\plugins\timber-library\vendor\twig\twig\src\Extension\DebugExtension.php:70:string '[contact-form-7 id="371" title="Contact form 1"]' (length=48)`

How would I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, so this `shortcodes` filter works perfectly just like this: `{{options.form.contact|shortcodes}}` It now outputs my Form on the page with no problems!